# PHP API returning wrong response for android app

Tags: php, android, api

I am creating a `API` for `android` developer in `PHP` in which he want to delete some values from database and want to show a message after that.
Now the problem is this data is deleting successfully but this API always shows else part message after complete the process. If I remove the **else part its return the `null` which crash the android** app. So I just want to give a proper `json` message to the android developer

> Here is the code which I am trying

```
 if($clear_my_property == "yes" && $clear_my_requirement == "yes" && $all_of_these == "yes"  && $user_name_id == $user_name_id1)
        {               
            $tables_count = array("property_for_sale","property_for_rent","cpo_post_requirements");

            foreach($tables_count as $table_count) 
            {

                $user_count = mysql_query("select * from $table_count where user_name = '$user_name'");
                $total_user_count = mysql_num_rows($user_count);

                if($total_user_count > 0)
                {

                    $tables_data = array("property_for_sale","property_for_rent","cpo_post_requirements");
                    foreach($tables_data as $table_data) 
                    {
                        $user_sql = mysql_query("delete from $table_data where user_name='$user_name'");

                        if($user_sql)
                        {
                            $response['success'] = 1;
                            $response['user']['error_msg'] = 'Clear Successfully All History!';             
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    $response['success'] = 0;
                    $response['user']['error_msg'] = 'Record Not Found!';
                }



            }       
        }
```

I know there is something wrong with this logic. But I need expert advise where my logic is wrong and what I have to do make it success

Comment: try this : 
if($total_user_count > 0)
                {

                    $tables_data = array("property_for_sale","property_for_rent","cpo_post_requirements");
                    foreach($tables_data as $table_data) 
                    {
                        $user_sql = mysql_query("delete from $table_data where user_name='$user_name'");
                                         
                    }
                    $response['success'] = 1;
                            $response['user']['error_msg'] = 'Clear Successfully All History!';
                } and remove else part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your original code, is that you are setting success/failure inside the loop. One of the four table may/may not contain the username. And if the last table don't have that, then as per your logic you are getting "record not found" even if previous iteration of the loop deleted data from the tables where username exists.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect(.....);
     if($clear_my_property == "yes" && $clear_my_requirement == "yes" && $all_of_these == "yes"  && $user_name_id == $user_name_id1) {               
                $tables_count = array("property_for_sale","property_for_rent","cpo_post_requirements");
                $userHistoryDeleted = 0;
                foreach($tables_count as $table_count) {
                     //if history is found, then it will be deleted otherwise not
                     mysql_query("delete from $table_count where user_name = '$user_name'");
                     if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) {
                          $userHistoryDeleted = 1;
                     }

                }
                $msg = 'Record Not Found!';
                if($userHistoryDeleted) {
                     $msg = 'Clear Successfully All History!';
                }
                $response['success'] = $userHistoryDeleted;
                $response['user']['error_msg'] = $msg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code :

```
if($total_user_count > 0)
                {

                    $tables_data = array("property_for_sale","property_for_rent","cpo_post_requirements");
                    foreach($tables_data as $table_data) 
                    {
                        $user_sql = mysql_query("delete from $table_data where user_name='$user_name'");

                        if($user_sql)
                        {
                            $response['success'] = 1;
                            $response['user']['error_msg'] = 'Clear Successfully All History!';             
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    $response['success'] = 0;
                    $response['user']['error_msg'] = 'Record Not Found!';
                }
```

to this one

```
if($total_user_count > 0)
                {

                    $tables_data = array("property_for_sale","property_for_rent","cpo_post_requirements");
                    foreach($tables_data as $table_data) 
                    {
                        $user_sql = mysql_query("delete from $table_data where user_name='$user_name'");

                    }
                    $response['success'] = 1;
                    $response['user']['error_msg'] = 'Clear Successfully All History!';
                }
```